# How to overlay two live images of the same scene having multiple calibrated cameras in python

Tags: python, camera, overlay, calibration

I have multiple cameras that are closely located to each other, looking at the same scene.
I can calibrate all of them (at once - currently using the openCV algorithm).
What I now want to do is, to overlay for example the following:
Let one camera be a LIDAR depth, the second a grayscale and the third an infrared cam. I want to overlay now the "grayscale scene" in an image format with the depth and infrared information being on the correct pixel. (Similar to depth-grayscale overlays that many 3D-cameras bring).
The cameras have different opening angles and resolutions.

I appreciate any hint or comment :-)
Cheers.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried so far? Basically you need to register the images onto each other, using a suitable distance measure or metric you need to minimize under allowed applicable transformations (such as affine transformations or homographies), find the transformation variables, apply the transform to the images and blend the values with a suitable colormap.

Comment: Hi Dschoni, thanks.

Comment: I have only yet calibrated following this [tutorial](https://longervision.github.io/2017/03/18/ComputerVision/OpenCV/opencv-internal-calibration-circle-grid/) . From this I get my intrinsic and extrensic parameters. Before starting further coding, I need to understand the principle of whats next. I thought so as well that a distance measure might be necessary - in order to know the "point on the epipolar line" -  but I have this from my depth sensor.  Now - how can I obtain the affine trans / homography?

Comment: Mapping different imaging modalities is non-trivial if you don't know the exact positions of cameras a-priori. Solve the inverse homographie e.g. to find a homography between two cameras. Apply the resulting matrix two one of the images and you're done. There is extended work on RGB to Lidar mapping e.g. here https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10109 or here http://rical.ce.gatech.edu/Papers/CONVR2016-Kim%20P%20and%20Cho.pdf however, if you're dealing with 2d representations of 3D data, you should be okay with simple registration (still non-trivial).

Comment: Hm - by calibrating and obtaining the extrensic parameters, in my understanding, I do know the positions of the cameras a p-priori? If so, do you have me a hint for "simple registration" as well?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html

Comment: Thanks again Dschoni. Wouldn't it become much easier, if I assumed the object to be in one fixed plane, defined by the calibration plate? Now I should be able to obtain the same world coordinates for all cameras - and now I wonder how to backproject them into one common plane. (Sth. similar to projectPoints)?

Comment: It would be easier but might lead to strange result especially when dealing with 3D data.